# What stronger alternatives are there to difflib?

Tags: python, string-comparison, difflib

I am working on script that needs to be able to track revisions.  The general idea is to give it a list of tuples where the first entry is the name of a field (ie "title" or "description" etc.), the second entry is the first version of that field, and the third entry is the revised version.  So something like this:

```
[("Title", "The first version of the title", "The second version of the title")]
```

Now, using `python docx` I want my script to create a word file that will show the original version, and the new version with the changes bolded. Example:

---

**Original Title:**

This is the first version of the title

**Revised Title:**

This is the **second** version of the title

---

The way that this is done in `python docx` is to create a list of tuples, where the first entry is the text, and the second one is the formatting.  So the way to create the revised title would be this:

```
paratext = [("This is the ", ''),("second",'b'),(" version of the title",'')]
```

Having recent discovered `difflib` I figured this would be a pretty easy task.  And indeed, for simple word replacements such as sample above, it is, and can be done with the following function:

```
def revFinder(str1,str2):
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, str1, str2)
    matches = s.get_matching_blocks()[:-1]

    paratext = []

    for i in range(len(matches)):
        print "------"
        print str1[matches[i][0]:matches[i][0]+matches[i][2]]
        print str2[matches[i][1]:matches[i][1]+matches[i][2]]
        paratext.append((str2[matches[i][1]:matches[i][1]+matches[i][2]],''))

        if i != len(matches)-1:
            print ""
            print str1[matches[i][0]+matches[i][2]:matches[i+1][0]]
            print str2[matches[i][1]+matches[i][2]:matches[i+1][1]]
            if len(str2[matches[i][1]+matches[i][2]:matches[i+1][1]]) > len(str1[matches[i][0]+matches[i][2]:matches[i+1][0]]):
                paratext.append((str2[matches[i][1]+matches[i][2]:matches[i+1][1]],'bu'))
            else:
                paratext.append((str1[matches[i][0]+matches[i][2]:matches[i+1][0]],'bu'))

    return paratext
```

The problems come when I want to do anything else.  For example, changing 'teh' to 'the' produces t **h** e **h** (without the spaces, I couldn't figure out the formatting).  Another issue is that extra text appended to the end is not shown as a change (or at all).

So, my question to all of you is what alternatives are there to `difflib` which are powerful enough to handle more complicated text comparions, or, how can I use `difflib` better such that it works for what I want?  Thanks in advance

Comment: [diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) does a great job for something like this.